# Can 'was' be omitted in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I believe it can't, because the omission of ***was*** makes ***valued*** and ***stigmatized*** paralleled.

> The thing they were good at at school wasn't valued, or ***was***
>   actually stigmatized.

Comment: If you wanted to remove one "was", you could say: *The thing they were good at in school was actually stigmatized or not valued.*

Comment: If you remove *was*, the sentence will still be grammatical. So, it's fine to do so. However, doing so would alter the meaning of the sentence, because it would then be saying that the thing they were good at *wasn't* stigmatized.

Comment: @AIQ That sounds quite clumsy.

Comment: As currently written, the wording is clumsy.  You might be better to rephrase it. Possibly something like:  At school, the thing they were good at was either stigmatized or not valued.

Comment: "At school, the thing they were good at was unvalued/undervalued, or actually stigmatized." or something like "Their best subject at school was unvalued, or actually stigmatized." (Substitute talent, class, ability, etc for subject.) Repeating "at" is bad style even if it's grammatical.

Answer (score 0):

No, "was" can't be omitted, for the reasons that you give.

Answer (score 0):

No.

If  you remove the word was you end up with the meaning that the 'thing' wasn't "valued or actually stigmatized", which still sounds clumsy but implies that although it wasn't valued, it wasn't stigmatized either.

The original sentence isn't great - a better way to phrase it would be:

> The thing they were good at at school wasn't valued, or was even
> stigmatized.